# Why does having the cursor in a text box give me an "index out of range" error?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, textbox

I've been working [Chris Meyers Tkinter tutorial](http://www.openbookproject.net/py4fun/gui/tkPhone.html) and noticed a weird exception.  When I run the program and "Load" one of the items in the listbox and update the info, if I leave the cursor anywhere in the box I get the following error:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

However, if I click outside of the boxes and click the update button it works perfectly fine.  Any ideas on why this occurs and how I could safeguard against it?  Here is the full program:

```
    from Tkinter import *
from phones  import *

def whichSelected () :
    print "At %s of %d" % (select.curselection(), len(phonelist))
    return int(select.curselection()[0])

def addEntry () :
    phonelist.append ([nameVar.get(), phoneVar.get()])
    setSelect ()

def updateEntry() :
    phonelist[whichSelected()] = [nameVar.get(), phoneVar.get()]
    setSelect ()

def deleteEntry() :
    del phonelist[whichSelected()]
    setSelect ()

def loadEntry  () :
    name, phone = phonelist[whichSelected()]
    nameVar.set(name)
    phoneVar.set(phone)

def makeWindow () :
    global nameVar, phoneVar, select
    win = Tk()

    frame1 = Frame(win)
    frame1.pack()

    Label(frame1, text="Name").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    nameVar = StringVar()
    name = Entry(frame1, textvariable=nameVar)
    name.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

    Label(frame1, text="Phone").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    phoneVar= StringVar()
    phone= Entry(frame1, textvariable=phoneVar)
    phone.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

    frame2 = Frame(win)       # Row of buttons
    frame2.pack()
    b1 = Button(frame2,text=" Add  ",command=addEntry)
    b2 = Button(frame2,text="Update",command=updateEntry)
    b3 = Button(frame2,text="Delete",command=deleteEntry)
    b4 = Button(frame2,text=" Load ",command=loadEntry)
    b1.pack(side=LEFT); b2.pack(side=LEFT)
    b3.pack(side=LEFT); b4.pack(side=LEFT)

    frame3 = Frame(win)       # select of names
    frame3.pack()
    scroll = Scrollbar(frame3, orient=VERTICAL)
    select = Listbox(frame3, yscrollcommand=scroll.set, height=6)
    scroll.config (command=select.yview)
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    select.pack(side=LEFT,  fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    return win

def setSelect () :
    phonelist.sort()
    select.delete(0,END)
    for name,phone in phonelist :
        select.insert (END, name)

win = makeWindow()
setSelect ()
win.mainloop()
```

and here is the contents of phones.py

```
    phonelist = [
  ['Meyers, Chris',  '343-4349'],
  ['Smith, Robert',  '689-1234'],
  ['Jones, Janet',   '483-5432'],
  ['Barnhart, Ralph','683-2341'],
  ['Nelson, Eric',   '485-2689'],
  ['Prefect, Ford',  '987-6543'],
  ['Zigler, Mary',   '567-8901'],
  ['Smith, Bob',     '689-1234']
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the select.curselection() - *which returns the indexes of selected items in the listbox* - returns an empty tuple - (), once you move away from the records list.

So in this case, once you click on the text boxes to update something, you are clearing the selected records list.

```
def whichSelected () :
    print "At %s of %d" % (select.curselection(), len(phonelist))
    return int(select.curselection()[0])
```

And that is why, just before you get the IndexError: tuple index out of range error, you also see

```
At () of 8
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 13, in updateEntry
    phonelist[whichSelected()] = [nameVar.get(), phoneVar.get()]
  File "main.py", line 6, in whichSelected
    return int(select.curselection()[0])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Once you press "Load" the details of the record are displayed in appropriate input fields (the text boxes in this case). Your selected record is still selected (so select.curselection() still has the item's index).

But once you update the record, you are also calling setSelect() to refresh the list of records.

```
def updateEntry() :
    phonelist[whichSelected()] = [nameVar.get(), phoneVar.get()]
    setSelect ()

def setSelect () :
    phonelist.sort()
    select.delete(0,END)
    for name,phone in phonelist :
        select.insert (END, name)
```

To update the same record as the one you previously did, you need to click on the relevant record again, so that the select.curselection() now knows which record to update.

To avoid doing that manually, you can try selection_set() to save the previous known location. For example, something like this:

```
def updateEntry() :
    phonelist[whichSelected()] = [nameVar.get(), phoneVar.get()]
    setSelect (index=whichSelected())

def setSelect (index=0) :
    if not len(phonelist):
        index = None
    phonelist.sort()
    select.delete(0,END)
    for name,phone in phonelist :
        select.insert (END, name)
    if index is not None:
        select.selection_set(index)
```

This would set the previous known item still selected. It also selects the first item in the list in every other operation. If the phonelist is empty, then of course, we won't select anything (thus, index = None)